# error installing npm install @salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest --save-dev

Tags: node.js, npm, trailblazer

I'm unable to install this, Jest Testing Framework setup please help me with is issue

Terminal:->

PS C:\Users\Akhilesh\Documents\GitHub\test-lwc>

```
npm install @salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest --save-dev
```

> npm ERR! code ETARGET npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for
> prettier-plugin-apex@^1.10.1. npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or
> one of your dependencies are requesting npm ERR! notarget a package
> version that doesn't exist.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\Akhilesh\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-11-08T07_48_01_695Z-debug.log
> PS C:\Users\Akhilesh\Documents\GitHub\test-lwc>

Answer (score 2):

edit your `package.json` file, change the line

```js
"prettier-plugin-apex": "^1.10.1"
```

to

```js
"prettier-plugin-apex": "^1.10.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

RUN > npm install prettier-plugin-apex@1.10.0 After running this you will be able to successfully run

npm install @salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest --save-dev